# Why is the face limit so low in A-Frame?

Tags: limit, aframe, face

I have a character in my scene that is less than 6k vertices and less than 2k faces. The face limit where it turns red in the stats seems to be 1k.

I have tried it on my desktop, a iPhone 7 and a Pixel 1. It runs at 60 fps on all three. Why is that limit so low?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue filed for this. https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3024

The answer is it shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot, I didn't see that issue. I will go by the vertices count and fps then. Cheers!